# Native MATLAB function for sequential evaluation of functions?

Tags: matlab, function, validation, call, sequential

So I was trying to polish my input validation in MATLAB functions and in the process I ended up creating the following function that really makes my code cleaner. I put it here in full in case someone finds it useful:

```
function [] = callFunctions(varargin)
%callFunctions Calls a sequence of functions on their respective arguments.
%   The inputs are expected as funcHdl1, {input1}, funcHdl2, {input2}, ...
%   Then callFunctions calls sequentially func1(input1); func2(input2); ...

%% === INPUT VALIDATION ===

% Check that the callFunctions has at least one argument
message = 'The number of arguments must be positive.';
assert(nargin > 0, message);

% Check that the callFunctions has an even number of arguments
message = 'The number of arguments must be even.';
assert(mod(nargin,2)==0,message);

% Name the handles
numHandles = nargin/2;
handleNames = cell(1,numHandles);
inputNames = cell(1,numHandles);
for k=1:numHandles
    handleNames{k} = 'handle';
    handleNames{k} = cat(2, handleNames{k}, int2str(k));
    inputNames{k} = 'input';
    inputNames{k} = cat(2, inputNames{k}, int2str(k));
end

% Function to check that the inputs are function handles
isValidFunctionHdl = @(x) validateattributes(x, {'function_handle'}, {});

% Create an input parser
p = inputParser;
% Add all arguments to check if they are handles. Don't check the inputs.
for k=1:numHandles
    p.addOptional(handleNames{k}, 0, isValidFunctionHdl);
    p.addOptional(inputNames{k}, 0);
end
% Parse the input
p.parse(varargin{:});


%% === PROGRAM ===

% Evaluate all the functions on their inputs
for k=1:numHandles
    feval(varargin{2*k-1},varargin{2*k}{:}); 
end

end
```

Now the last part called `%% === PROGRAM ===` is the important part. It just evaluates the functions `func1, func2, func3, ...` on their respective inputs `input1, input2, input3, ...`, all of which are given as inputs to `callFunctions`. It is called as:

```
callFunctions(funcHdl1, {input1}, funcHdl2, {input2}, ...)
```

My question is simple: is there a native MATLAB function that does what `callFunctions` does? I use this during input validation (in combination with `assert` and `validateattributes`). So Ì intend to use `callFunctions` in nearly every function I write. I'd like to use the least custom functions possible for this.

Ben

EDIT: I didn't want to go into this to keep the post short. But yes there is a context where this seems necessary for me. This is when I do input validation with the input parser. I often need to check multiple conditions, like this (completely made up example):

```
% Made up function to illustrate context
function [] = myFunction(input)

% Create an input parser
p = inputParser;
% Create functions to validate input. Must be a 2d logical array with at least one false value
isValidArray = @(x) validateattributes(x, {'logical'}, {'2d'});
hasAtLeastOneFalse = @(x) assert(length(find(x)) < length(x), 'Must be at least one false.');
isValidInput = @(x) callFunctions( isValidArray, {x}, hasAtLeastOneFalse, {x} );
% Add the required input
p.addRequired('input', isValidInput);
% Parse the input
p.parse(input);

end
```

This makes my code much cleaner because it allows me to combine multiple `validateattributes` and `assert` statements in the call to `addRequired`.

Comment: _is there a native MATLAB function that does this?_ That does what, exactly?

Comment: That does what `callFunctions` does.

Comment: Wouldn't `eval` on a cell of strings be an easier way?

Comment: `eval` is dangerous (it can evaluate arbitrary code), and inefficient, so it should be avoided

Comment: @Ben You should then explain what the function does. It's easier than requiring potential answerers to read your code and deduce its intent

Comment: @LuisMendo I have clearly explained what the function does, both in the header of the function, and in the explanation after it.

The function calls other functions and applies them to their respective inputs. I even provided an example of its use.

Comment: @LuisMendo is right. In my opinion, the question is unclear. At the beginning you talk abut input validation, so [this should contain valuable information](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/input-parser-validation-functions.html).

Comment: @m3tho This was just to explain the context in which I needed it. I said: "In the process I ended up creating the following function which really makes my code cleaner."

I'm sorry if that diverted your attention, but I thought that the rest of the post stood clearly on its own.

Comment: @m3tho I am aware of the inputParser... I use it in the example code in my post. This was not the point.

Comment: @Ben May I ask you why you need `callFunctions()` to call other functions instead of a simple script where you directly execute them?

Comment: My comment got long so I just added it as an answer.  Basically No Matlab doesn't have this built in & I don't see the benefit.

Comment: @m3tho Because I need to be able to pass variable input to each of the functions, as in the example code I appended in an edit to my post. Unless I'm mistaken, I cannot pass arguments to a script. Can I?

Comment: @Ben A script doesn't accept any input, but in a script you can call functions and directly specify their input obtaining the same result as `callFunction()`

Comment: I completely understand your confusion. It is exactly the essence of my question: it SEEMS to me that this should not require me to build a custom function. Nevertheless, it's the only way I found to make the code in `myFunction` in the edit to my post work.

Comment: @m3tho Yes but I need to reuse it time and time again. I can't write a script for each time I use it. It has to be a function that calls other functions, leaving the input unspecified.

Comment: What you're asking for is covered in the linked duplicate, but a simpler approach would be to just make a nested or local function that does all the checks, then pass its function handle to `addRequired`.

Comment: @gnovice Thank you. I had completely forgotten that you could do nested functions in MATLAB. I think the nested function is the best option, because it allows me to access the inputs that have already been checked.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like this that I know of that already exists ... and I am not sure why there would be.

Basically you are trading this:

```
func1(input1);
func2(input2);
```

For this:

```
callFunctions(@func1, {input1}, @func2, {input2})
```

All I see this doing is a bunch of input checking that `callFunctions` was used correctly.  Assuming each individual function is written well and has it own asserts etc ... I don't get the need for this at all.  Besides making it harder to read.

You could either skip it entirely or just have a simple for loop for a list of FCN handles & inputs.  Each function would handle its own errors and you wouldn't be adding a bunch of code around something that seems pretty straight forward.

**EDIT:**
To your example usage:  Why not do something like this?  To me this is much "cleaner" than your example which seems to be your goal.

```
function [] = myFunction(input)
% Create an input parser
p = inputParser;
% Must be a 2d logical array with at least one false value
addRequired(p, 'input', @(x) validateattributes(x, {'logical'}, {'2d'}));
p.parse(input);
assert(length(find(input)) < length(input), 'Must be at least one false.')
disp('Running rest of code with good inputs!')
```

Which handles all your cases for bad inputs:

```
>> myFunction(ones(2,2,2))
Error using myFunction (line 6)
The value of 'input' is invalid. Expected input to be
one of these types:
logical
Instead its type was double.

>> myFunction(true(2,2,2))
Error using myFunction (line 6)
The value of 'input' is invalid. Expected input to be two-dimensional.

>> myFunction(true(1,2))
Error using myFunction (line 7)
Must be at least one false.

>> myFunction([true false])
Running rest of code with good inputs!
```

Comment: I've added an edit to my post to show the context in which I use it. I use it like this all the time. I didn't want to go into the details because I wanted to keep the focus on the function itself.

I put the input validation in the code for `callFunctions` in case someone just wanted to copy and paste `callFunctions`. As I said in my post, it's clearly indicated as input validation and you can ignore it. I stated that the important part was the last part.

Thank you for your answer! I will just use my function if there is no native function.

Comment: In short, I'm forced to do this because the `addRequired` method accepts only a single validation function as input. I'm sorry to have confused everyone. Maybe I'll rewrite a post with the problem explained more clearly.

Comment: @Ben  See my edit to your example usage. The code seems cleaner to me without `callFunctions` and handles the same bad input cases ... unless I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks, it's true that this also works well enough. I just felt it was better form and more coherent to handle all errors within the `inputParser`. This way I define what makes my input valid only once and then I validate it only once. I understand if you call me OCD ;). But maybe your solution is indeed the simplest in the end.